# Script to switch columns according to their positive/negative increment

Tags: awk, sed

The situation: I have 5 columns. Columns 2 and 3 are min and max ranges and column 4 is a value to indicate positive or negative increment (1 or -1). Columns 1 and 5 are ignored.

However, columns 2 and 3 are currently min (lowest number) to max (highest number), and if column 4 is -1 I want them to be switched. Which script in Linux can do this?

The text files looks like this (first 2 rows out of 400): 
**44110,2100,2600,1,1 

44200,3400,4500,-1,2**

Therefore, in the output the second row would contain the switch and the first row would stay the same, as follows:  
**44110,2100,2600,1,1 

44200,4500,3400,-1,2**

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: better post your attempts. Since you tagged awk and sed, you may know how to do some basic attempts

Comment: I haven't made any attempts to be honest because I have no idea. I put awk because it was a guess that awk would be the right approach.

Comment: Uhms it would be good if you go and read [ask]. We are missing a clear sample input / desired output. And then, it is good to show some attempt, any, because otherwise it looks like we are doing your homework here :) You have asked [some questions already](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4657967/daniel-clemence?tab=questions), should be aware of this.

Comment: I have made a slight edit to show the input/output in a clearer way. On the last point, yes - but since I do not know how to attempt it I came here for help.

Comment: I've now got an awk script which has solved this. Still, it was worth asking here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $4<0{t=$3;$3=$2;$2=t} 1' file
44110,2100,2600,1,1
44200,4500,3400,-1,2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went with this option in the end: awk  -F , '
{ 
if (NR<=1) {
print $0
} 
}
{
if ($4 == 1)
{
print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5
}
else if ($4 == -1)
{
print $1 "," $3 "," $2 "," $4 "," $5
}
}
'               input_file.txt > output_file.txt

Comment: Why would you want to do that vs just swapping the 2 fields if necessary like I showed? Once you have some more experience using awk (or even just programming in general) you'll look back on the script you posted and wonder what on earth you were thinking.